# What is the meaning of manual in /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: networking, interface

I saw several Ubuntu hosts in which there was an entry which was defined as "manual" (as opposed to other entries which were "static" or "dhcp"). While I do understand what it the meaning for "static" and "dhcp", I don't know what is meant by "manual". Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

"Manual" means that the interface will not get started automatically. You will need to run `ifup` to get it up. ;-)